# How to convert Crypto-js decrypt (ECB + Padding) to PHP code

Tags: php, cryptojs

I reading many posts about convert Crypto-js to PHP and trying all day long. All not work as my expected. It really hard for me to know how to convert Crypto-js to PHP code, i need help to convert below code to PHP.

**Can you help me with the following code into PHP:**

```
const t = cryptojs.enc.Base64.parse('sometext');

const e = cryptojs.AES.decrypt('anothertext', t, {
            mode: cryptojs.mode.ECB,
            padding: cryptojs.pad.Pkcs7, 
        });
```

My PHP Code:

```
$cipher = "AES-256-ECB";
$key = 'sometext';
$chiperRaw = base64_decode('anothertext');
$originalPlaintext = openssl_decrypt($chiperRaw, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
```

Comment: please share your PHP code as well

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir i just updated my php code :)

Comment: It is a good cryptographic practise to provide sample data to prove that the cross platform method is working correctly. So please provide a full set of data you are working with in crypto-js-side (plaintext, key, ciphertext). Your constants on PHP-side do have a 'ciphertext' that is no Base64-code so this will fail definitely. On js-side is the same, so it is more arguing.